# How to pass some data from View to controller in angularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cookies

```
 `<tr ng-repeat="x in rest">
   <td>{{ x.groupId }}</td>
    <td><a  href="#/offers">{{ x.groupName }}</a></td>
  </tr>`
```

this is the code of my view. I want to pass the group id back to controller so that i can run another API which uses this groupId to fetch contacts. I tried Using cookies for this but i receive an error

```
`Uncaught ReferenceError: $cookies is not defined` at my controller at `line:1`
```

Comment: Your controller already knows the groupId, why would you want to pass it back? **EDIT**: To use it in /offers? You could use [URL parameters](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing data to controller is very simple.You can do it as below-:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in rest">
   <td>{{ x.groupId }}</td>
   <td><a  href="#/offers/{{ x.groupId }}">{{ x.groupName }}</a></td>
</tr>
```

RouteConfig:

```
  when('/offers/:groupId', {
        templateUrl: 'ViewName.html',
        controller: 'CtrlName'
      }).
```

Controller code:

```
 TestControllers.controller('CtrlName', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
      function($scope, $routeParams) {
        $scope.groupId = $routeParams.groupId ;
      }]);
```

For reference you can check -:https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you so much. Worked for me. I was almost there via the same method but taking a long long way. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

you can pass data from views to controller using

```
ngModel


//sample Views
<form name="testForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <input ng-model="val" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" name="anim" class="my-input"
     aria-describedby="inputDescription" />
</form>

//sample Controller
<script>
  angular.module('inputExample', [])
   .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.val = '1';
  }]);
</script>
```